# Write to windows share mounted in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, samba, mount, server-message-block, fstab

I used to mount a windows share in Ubuntu server, with an entry in fstab:

```
//data/SharedFolder /media/SharedFolder/ smbfs user,defaults,credentials=/root/.creds,uid=root,gid=root 0 0
```

/root/.creds is a text file with three lines, my username, password and domain.

Users on the ubuntu server could write to this mount, but then I upgraded to 10.04 and now only root can write. Regular users can still read though.

`mount` currently tells me:

```
//data/SharedFolder on /media/SharedFolder type cifs (rw,mand,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
```

How do I make it world writeable again?

Thanks

Comment: I've tried adding a umask parameter (umask=0000), but don't seem to affect the permssions.

I also changed the gid from 'root' to a group that all users are in, but as the group still doens't have write permission, this didn't help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you'll want to change your filesystem type from smbfs to cifs in your /etc/fstab entry. That'll change how things behave just because of that.

Also, you might want to look into using the 'noperm' mount-flag. This tells the server to not do ACL checks, and rely on the server hosting the mounted share to provide that. If you really want everyone to get access to that share, this could represent a large bat to accomplish this.